# LDAP login works via terminal on CentOS, but doesn't work via GUI

Tags: authentication, centos, ldap

I had configured LDAP server on CentOS and I configured the client as well.  The client will log in by terminal, but the problem is the user not able to log in via GUI - there are authentication errors.

Comment: Post the authentication error and what you've done so far to investigate the issue.

Comment: Dec 13 12:19:25 sellcraft nfsidmap[2334]: nss_getpwnam: name 'root@example.com' does not map into domain 'redhat.com'
Dec 13 12:19:25 sellcraft nfsidmap[2338]: nss_getpwnam: name 'ldapuser1@example.com' does not map into domain 'redhat.com'